How To Get Relative Paths When Zipping multiple files in Python on Windows
I am attempting to create a function that automatically runs through a folder and puts all of the files into a single .zip file and while I have it working, it is creating a nest of folders inside the zip file that go all the way up to the drive letter.
import sys
import os
from zipfile import ZipFile

def ZipItUp():
    '''
    Zips up the content of the folder "ZipThisUp"
    '''
    cwd = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    os.chdir(cwd)
    sourceDir = os.path.join(cwd, 'ZipThisUp')


    zipFilePath = os.path.join(sourceDir, 'MyZipFile.zip')
    if os.path.exists(zipFilePath):
        os.remove(zipFilePath)
    
    itemsInDir = []

    for root, _, files in os.walk(sourceDir):
        for filename in files:
            filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
            itemsInDir.append(filepath)


    with ZipFile(zipFilePath, 'w') as myZip:
        for item in itemsInDir:
            # Include everything in the folder except for the python cache files,
            # They'll be re-cached on the other machine
            if os.path.basename(item) != '__pycache__':
                myZip.write(item)
    return

The issue I'm running into here is what I presume to be a Windows file pathing issue (although I'm not fully sure because I haven't tried this on Linux)
The zip file gets generated in the exact spot I expected but when I open it, it is a series of nested folders of C > User > Documents > ZipThisUp > Then my files
When I am hoping to either have the .zip file just contain my files or a single folder for "ZipThisUp" that contains my files
The beginning of my code where I am doing os.chdir(cwd) is me attempting to force os.path to utilize relative pathing instead of absolute pathing.
I was originally using os.listdir instead of os.walk, and that lead to errors saying that the files couldn't be found, and switching to os.walk got the .zip file to actually generate, but with the full paths.
I then tried including os.path.basename() and os.path.realpath(__file__) and that resulted in the file not found errors coming back.
I looked around to try to find another post that contained this issue but I was unable to find one, any help will be greatly appreciated.

As mentioned in this post, an easy workarround is to use the shutil library and compress the whole folder.
If you still want to use zipfile note that the write() method take another parameters:
ZipFile.write(filename, arcname=None, compress_type=None, compresslevel=None)

If arcname is empty, the name used to save each file is equal to the complete path (a.k.a filename), but you can specify a different arcname. Thus, you can delete the sourceDirin each one of the the item, something like this:
 with ZipFile(zipFilePath, 'w') as myZip:
    for item in itemsInDir:
        # Include everything in the folder except for the python cache files,
        # They'll be re-cached on the other machine
        if os.path.basename(item) != '__pycache__':
            arcname = item.replace(f'{sourceDir}\\', '')
            myZip.write(item, arcname)


When zipping a file, you can specify an alternate name to store the file in the archive.  Below the zip_it_up function takes a folder, resolves its absolute path name, then creates a zip file in the same directory as the folder being compressed, adding all the files beneath it using archive names relative to the folder's parent.
Note also I used pathlib for path manipulation:
import sys
import os
import zipfile
import pathlib

def zip_it_up(folder):
    src = pathlib.Path(folder).resolve()  # absolute path to folder
    if not src.is_dir():
        raise ValueError('not a directory')
    zipname = src.with_suffix(src.suffix + '.zip')
    zipname.unlink(missing_ok=True)
    
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zipname, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED, 9) as dest:
        for root, _, files in src.walk():
            for file in files:
                abspath = root / file
                if file != '__pycache__':
                    relpath = abspath.relative_to(src)
                    print(f'adding: {relpath}')
                    dest.write(abspath, relpath)

zip_it_up('ZipItUp')

